# How to remove authentication for introspection query in Graphql

Tags: node.js, authorization, graphql, introspection, apollo-server

so may be this is very basic question so please bear with me. Let me explain what I am doing and what I really need.

---

**EXPLANATION**

---

I have created a graphql server by using **ApolloGraphql** (apollo-server-express npm module).

Here is the code snippet to give you an idea.

**api.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import rootSchema from './root-schema'
.... // some extra code
app = express.router()
app.use(jwtaAuthenticator) // --> this code authenticates Authorization header
.... // some more middleware's added
const graphQLServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema: rootSchema, // --> this is root schema object
  context: context => context,
  introspection: true, 
})
graphQLServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' })
```

**server.js**

```
import http from 'http'
import express from 'express'
import apiRouter from './api' // --> the above file
const app = express()
app.use([some middlewares])
app.use('/', apiRouter)
....
....
export async function init () {

try {
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app)
  httpServer
    .listen(PORT)
    .on('error', (err) => { setTimeout(() => process.exit(1), 5000) })
  } catch (err) {
    setTimeout(() => process.exit(1), 5000)
  }
  console.log('Server started --- ', PORT)
}
export default app
```

**index.js**

```
require('babel-core')
require('babel-polyfill')
require = require('esm')(module/* , options */)
const server = require('./server.js') // --> the above file

server.init()
```

---

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

---

I am using **node index.js** to start the app. So, the app is expecting **Authorization** header (JWT token) to be present all the times, even for the **introspection** query. But this is not what I want, I want that introspection query will be resolvable even without the token. So that anyone can see the documentation.

Please shed some light and please guide what is the best approach to do so. Happy coding :)

Comment: Trying to solve the same issue in a Spring Boot GraphQL server, still no luck.

Answer (score 14):

`.startsWith('query Introspection')` is **insecure** because any query can be named `Introspection`.

The better approach is to check the whole query.

First import graphql and prepare introspection query string:

```js
const { parse, print, getIntrospectionQuery } = require('graphql');
// format introspection query same way as apollo tooling do
const introspectionQuery = print(parse(getIntrospectionQuery()));
```

Then in Apollo Server configuration check query:

```js
context: ({ req }) => {
  // allow introspection query
  if (req.body.query === introspectionQuery) {
    return {};
  }

  // continue
}
```

Comment: what if there are some small tweaks in the `req.body.query` introspection query that differ just slightly from the generated `inrospectionQuery` on the backend? Or maybe that is unlikely?

Comment: If you use same version of graphql package in client and server then there should not be any differences in the query.

Comment: I think testing using `req.body.query.trim().startsWith('query Introspection')` is an acceptable, because the developers are in control of what the queries are called, and "don't start a query name with Introspection" should be one of the rules for naming them. It is similar to the risk from SQL injection - there needs be be a query defined with a name that starts with Introspection for this to be a risk. Users cannot add queries to the schema - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of different ways to handle authorization in GraphQL, as illustrated in [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/authentication):

> - Adding middleware for `express` (or some other framework like `hapi` or `koa`)
> - Checking for authorization inside individual resolvers
> - Checking for authorization inside your data models
> - Utilizing [custom directives](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/creating-directives#enforcing-access-permissions)

Adding express middleware is great for preventing unauthorized access to your entire schema. If you want to allow unauthenticated access to some fields but not others, it's generally recommended you move your authorization logic from the framework layer to the GraphQL or data model layer using one of the methods above.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I will check it out.

Answer (score -3):

So finally I found the solution and here is what I did.

Let me first tell you that there were **2 middle-wares** added on **base path**. Like this:

```
app //--> this is express.Router()
  .use(jwtMw) // ---> these are middlewares
  .use(otherMw)
```

The **jwtMw** is the one that **checks the authentication of the user**, and since even **introspection** query comes under this MW, it used to **authenticate** that as well. So, after some research I found this solution:

**jwtMw.js**

```
function addJWTMeta (req, res, next) {
   // we can check for null OR undefined and all, then check for query Introspection, with better condition like with ignore case
   if (req.body.query.trim().startsWith('query Introspection')) {
      req.isIntrospection = true
      return next()
   }
   ...
   ...
   // ---> extra code to do authentication of the USER based on the Authorization header
}
export default addJWTMeta
```

**otherMw.js**

```
function otherMw (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isIntrospection) return next()
  ...
  ...
  // ---> extra code to do some other context creation
}
export default otherMw
```

So here in **jwtMw.js** we are checking that if the **query is Introspection** just add a variable in **req** object and move forward, and in next middleware after the **jwtMw.js** whosoever wants to check for introspection query just check for that **variable (isIntrospection, in this case)** and if it is present and is **true**, please move on. We can add this code and **scale to every middleware** that if **req.isIntrospection** is there just carry on or do the actual processing otherwise.

Happy coding :)